# Is there a way that I can convert a parquet file to avro (directly or indirectly)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parquet, avro

I'm quite new to this and currently exploring ways of converting parquet file to avro. This is mainly due to the requirement of deserialising the avro file and get the schema.

I tried to read the parquet file first as a Dataframe through pandas and then writing it as an avro (not sure whether this is the optimal way), and finally get the schema from it. But did not succeed

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('local_output-00000-of-00001.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
df.write.format("avro").save("deserialize.avro")
```

was getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'

I assume the above approach is not the right way to do it. Tried to find ways on the web, but couldn't find a constructive answer, thus decided to post it. Would really appreciate to hear from anyone who has done this before, or have different approaches to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you're trying PySpark DataFrame functions here `df.write.format("avro").save("deserialize.avro")` while working with a Pandas DatFrame.

You can write data to an AVRO file from Pandas by the following code.

First, you need to create/find the schema of the data.
e.g.

```
schema = {
    'name': 'malldata',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'Column1', 'type': 'int'},
        {'name': 'Column2', 'type': 'string'},
    ]
}
```

Then, you need to convert Pandas DataFrame into a `dict`, using `fastavro` module, you can write the `dict` to an AVRO file, using this schema.

Your overall code would look like this.

```
import pandas as pd
from fastavro import writer, parse_schema, reader

schema = {
    'name': 'data',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'Column1', 'type': 'int'},
        {'name': 'Column2', 'type': 'string'},
    ]
}
parsed_schema = parse_schema(schema)

df = pd.read_parquet('local_output-00000-of-00001.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
records = df.to_dict('records')

with open('data.avro', 'wb') as out:
    writer(out, parsed_schema, records)
```

You can refer to [this](https://dev.to/rumsinha/pandas-dataframe-to-avro-1hll) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier also, `df.write(...)` is pyspark function.

If you want to use pyspark to convert parquet to avro, you can do it this way:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf

app_name = "AvroConversion"
master = "local[1]"

conf = SparkConf().setAppName(app_name).setMaster(master)

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

file_path = 'inputfile.parquet'
df = spark.read.format('parquet').load(file_path)
df.write.format("avro").save("avro_output.avro")
```